# Web maps api to see in 45 deg angle

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-maps, maps

I've been searching for a map API that allows me to see in a 45 degree angle, such as Google Earth does.

So far I haven't found any, and I know that Google Maps and Bing Maps do not have this function. And any others found do not include the country required: Portugal.

I'm searching for, preferably, a map that is not installed by a plugin, but in last case, I will work with that.

Answer (score 0):

With  google maps this is possible. You must use the `tilt` property in mapOptions

```
var mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.964645, -122.01523),
   zoom: 18,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
   tilt: 45
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),   mapOptions);
}
```

Look at this sample [from google dev](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-simple)

Comment: Edit: Like I said, it has to work for Portugal, and this case it doesn't, apparently. That map view in PT is from above.

Comment: I'm sorry if in Portugal are not yet available satellite images updated with the display capability, it depends from area to area and when it is updated. This is to check if the area you're interested in has already been photographed with this technique. But the fact remains that Google Maps has this feature.

Comment: Well yeah, but thats why I'm here, because I'm searching for another one. I've seen this before (or my co-workers) and ruled it out, hence the question here.